Displace Modifier ignores UVs
I want to displace mesh then export STL with the updated mesh. I try to map Modier displacement with UV but it seems not working at all.
Did you already see this issue ? Do you know how I can solve out ? I use Blender 4.2.2 LTS.



Hello does it work if you choose Coordinates > UV? If not, please pack the image (File > External Data > Pack Resources) then share the file

Apart from the image seemingly not being placed correctly - is that the mesh you want to displace with a modifier? Six triangles in a circle? There is no geometry inbetween, how is the modifier supposed to displace this? It needs vertices which can be displaced.
